# KendallTau: Trying to get more details on weightedtau() in stats.py

Tags: python, statistics

In stats.py I see the following import:

```
from ._stats import (_kendall_dis, _toint64, _weightedrankedtau,
                     _local_correlations)
```

and it is used in `weightedtau(...)` as: `_weightedrankedtau(x, y, rank, weigher, additive)`

Where can I find more details on the **implementation of `_weightedrankedtau()`**?

Comment: there are 3 references here in the doc: https://scipy.github.io/devdocs/generated/scipy.stats.weightedtau.html#scipy.stats.weightedtau I'm not clear if you are asking for these references (it can be difficult to locate the correct version of the docs online) or are you asking for the source code itself, or something else?

Comment: Thanks Lucas. I am looking for the source code itself for __weightedrankedtau()

Comment: Source code is here: https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/2850365/scipy/stats/stats.py#L4567-L4739

Comment: also, the original PR is here: https://github.com/scipy/scipy/pull/6763   perhaps the discussion is helpful, if not feel free to ignore.

Comment: I posted an answer with links and explanation. Feel free to mark as correct if this answers your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clarified in comments that the OP is asking for the location of the source code for calculation of the weighted Kendall tau.

The source code for function is located here:

https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/2850365/scipy/stats/stats.py#L4567-L4739

which is the python code. The workhorse function however, is the Cython code for `_weightedrankedtau` is located here:

https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/stats/_stats.pyx#L173

and a version of the docs for the python function is here:
https://scipy.github.io/devdocs/generated/scipy.stats.weightedtau.html#scipy.stats.weightedtau

finally the link to the PR which merged this method has some discussion that may be informative if you're interested in why is structured this way:

looks like pre-work on kendall tau before adding the weighted feature:
https://github.com/scipy/scipy/pull/5754

and this one implements:
https://github.com/scipy/scipy/pull/6763